# Maya MPxNode multiple outputs

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I'm trying to create an `MPxNode` with multiple outputs, but I can only get one to work properly. The other output doesn't set properly after connecting the node and during undos.

Is it possible to set both outputs at the same time in `compute` like how I'm trying to? It does work if I change the first line in compute to `if plug != self.output1 and plug != self.output2`, but that means it would calculate twice which is a waste of memory. And you could imagine how bad this would be if there were even more outputs.

I managed to minimize the code to this simple example. I'm scripting it in Python on Maya 2018:

```
import maya.OpenMayaMPx as OpenMayaMPx
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


class MyAwesomeNode(OpenMayaMPx.MPxNode):

    # Define node properties.
    kname = "myAwesomeNode"
    kplugin_id = OpenMaya.MTypeId(0x90000005)

    # Define node attributes.
    in_val = OpenMaya.MObject()
    output1 = OpenMaya.MObject()
    output2 = OpenMaya.MObject()

    def __init__(self):
        OpenMayaMPx.MPxNode.__init__(self)

    def compute(self, plug, data):
        # Only operate on output1 attribute.
        if plug != self.output1:
            return OpenMaya.kUnknownParameter

        # Get input value.
        val = data.inputValue(MyAwesomeNode.in_val).asFloat()

        # Set output 2.
        # This fails when setting up the node and during undos.
        out_plug_2 = data.outputValue(self.output2)
        if val > 0:
            out_plug_2.setFloat(1)
        else:
            out_plug_2.setFloat(0)
        out_plug_2.setClean()

        # Set output 1.
        # This works as expected.
        out_plug_1 = data.outputValue(self.output1)
        out_plug_1.setFloat(val)
        out_plug_1.setClean()

        data.setClean(plug)

        return True


def creator():
    return OpenMayaMPx.asMPxPtr(MyAwesomeNode())


def initialize():
    nattr = OpenMaya.MFnNumericAttribute()

    MyAwesomeNode.output2 = nattr.create("output2", "output2", OpenMaya.MFnNumericData.kFloat)
    nattr.setWritable(False)
    nattr.setStorable(False)
    MyAwesomeNode.addAttribute(MyAwesomeNode.output2)

    MyAwesomeNode.output1 = nattr.create("output1", "output1", OpenMaya.MFnNumericData.kFloat)
    nattr.setWritable(False)
    nattr.setStorable(False)
    MyAwesomeNode.addAttribute(MyAwesomeNode.output1)

    MyAwesomeNode.in_val = nattr.create("input", "input", OpenMaya.MFnNumericData.kFloat, 1)
    nattr.setKeyable(True)
    MyAwesomeNode.addAttribute(MyAwesomeNode.in_val)
    MyAwesomeNode.attributeAffects(MyAwesomeNode.in_val, MyAwesomeNode.output2)
    MyAwesomeNode.attributeAffects(MyAwesomeNode.in_val, MyAwesomeNode.output1)


def initializePlugin(obj):
    plugin = OpenMayaMPx.MFnPlugin(obj, "Me", "1.0", "Any")
    try:
        plugin.registerNode(MyAwesomeNode.kname, MyAwesomeNode.kplugin_id, creator, initialize)
    except:
        raise RuntimeError, "Failed to register node: '{}'".format(MyAwesomeNode.kname)


def uninitializePlugin(obj):
    plugin = OpenMayaMPx.MFnPlugin(obj)
    try:
        plugin.deregisterNode(MyAwesomeNode.kplugin_id)
    except:
        raise RuntimeError, "Failed to register node: '{}'".format(MyAwesomeNode.kname)


# Example usage of node
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import maya.cmds as cmds

    cmds.createNode("transform", name="result")
    cmds.setAttr("result.displayLocalAxis", True)

    cmds.createNode("myAwesomeNode", name="myAwesomeNode")
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output1", "result.translateX")

    # This output fails.
    cmds.polyCube(name="cube")
    cmds.setAttr("cube.translate", 0, 3, 0)
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output2", "cube.scaleX")
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output2", "cube.scaleY")
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output2", "cube.scaleZ")
```

Comment: In the compute method you could try to check for both outputs: `if plug != self.output1 and plug != self.output2:`.

Comment: Hey Haggi, check my question because I mentioned that. Doing that works, the problem is it recalculates compute twice. I really only need to do compute a single time then set all outputs, so I'm trying to optimize.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't read it correctly. You could cache the results of the first compute until it has to be recalculated. You can check for dirty attributes or simply check if inputs have changed, if not, then use the cached values.

Comment: I think I got something trying to cache the results! Just need to make sure it's stable on open/import/reference and so on. I'll post an answer if I manage to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which is working as expected. All outputs still must go through `compute()` but only one output will do the actual heavy calculations.

When going through `compute`, it checks all output plugs if any are clean. If all are dirty, then we need to re-calculate, otherwise if we do find one clean plug we can just use the cached values we saved earlier.

Here's an example:

```
import maya.OpenMayaMPx as OpenMayaMPx
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


class MyAwesomeNode(OpenMayaMPx.MPxNode):

    # Define node properties.
    kname = "myAwesomeNode"
    kplugin_id = OpenMaya.MTypeId(0x90000005)

    # Define node attributes.
    in_val = OpenMaya.MObject()
    output1 = OpenMaya.MObject()
    output2 = OpenMaya.MObject()

    def __init__(self):
        OpenMayaMPx.MPxNode.__init__(self)

        # Store value here.
        self.cached_value = 0

    def compute(self, plug, data):
        # Include all outputs here.
        if plug != self.output1 and plug != self.output2:
            return OpenMaya.kUnknownParameter

        # Get plugs.
        val = data.inputValue(MyAwesomeNode.in_val).asFloat()
        out_plug_1 = data.outputValue(self.output1)
        out_plug_2 = data.outputValue(self.output2)

        dep_node = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode(self.thisMObject())

        # Determine if this output needs to recalculate or simply use cached values.
        use_cache_values = False

        for name in ["output1", "output2"]:
            mplug = dep_node.findPlug(name)
            if data.isClean(mplug):
                # If we find a clean plug then just use cached values.
                use_cache_values = True
                break

        if use_cache_values:
            # Use cached value.
            value = self.cached_value
        else:
            # Calculate value.
            # We potentially can make big computations here.
            self.cached_value = val
            value = val

        # Set output 1.
        if plug == self.output1:
            out_plug_1.setFloat(value)
            out_plug_1.setClean()

        # Set output 2.
        if plug == self.output2:
            if value > 0:
                out_plug_2.setFloat(1)
            else:
                out_plug_2.setFloat(0)
            out_plug_2.setClean()

        data.setClean(plug)

        return True


def creator():
    return OpenMayaMPx.asMPxPtr(MyAwesomeNode())


def initialize():
    nattr = OpenMaya.MFnNumericAttribute()

    MyAwesomeNode.output2 = nattr.create("output2", "output2", OpenMaya.MFnNumericData.kFloat)
    nattr.setWritable(False)
    nattr.setStorable(False)
    MyAwesomeNode.addAttribute(MyAwesomeNode.output2)

    MyAwesomeNode.output1 = nattr.create("output1", "output1", OpenMaya.MFnNumericData.kFloat)
    nattr.setWritable(False)
    nattr.setStorable(False)
    MyAwesomeNode.addAttribute(MyAwesomeNode.output1)

    MyAwesomeNode.in_val = nattr.create("input", "input", OpenMaya.MFnNumericData.kFloat, -1)
    nattr.setKeyable(True)
    MyAwesomeNode.addAttribute(MyAwesomeNode.in_val)

    # Include both outputs.
    MyAwesomeNode.attributeAffects(MyAwesomeNode.in_val, MyAwesomeNode.output1)
    MyAwesomeNode.attributeAffects(MyAwesomeNode.in_val, MyAwesomeNode.output2)


def initializePlugin(obj):
    plugin = OpenMayaMPx.MFnPlugin(obj, "Me", "1.0", "Any")
    try:
        plugin.registerNode(MyAwesomeNode.kname, MyAwesomeNode.kplugin_id, creator, initialize)
    except:
        raise RuntimeError, "Failed to register node: '{}'".format(MyAwesomeNode.kname)


def uninitializePlugin(obj):
    plugin = OpenMayaMPx.MFnPlugin(obj)
    try:
        plugin.deregisterNode(MyAwesomeNode.kplugin_id)
    except:
        raise RuntimeError, "Failed to register node: '{}'".format(MyAwesomeNode.kname)


# Example usage of node
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import maya.cmds as cmds

    cmds.createNode("transform", name="result")
    cmds.setAttr("result.displayLocalAxis", True)

    cmds.createNode("myAwesomeNode", name="myAwesomeNode")
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output1", "result.translateX")

    # This output fails.
    cmds.polyCube(name="cube")
    cmds.setAttr("cube.translate", 0, 3, 0)
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output2", "cube.scaleX")
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output2", "cube.scaleY")
    cmds.connectAttr("myAwesomeNode.output2", "cube.scaleZ")
```

The outputs seem to be reacting ok when re-opening the file, when importing it to a new scene, and referencing it. I just need to transfer the same idea to c++ then it'll be golden.

Comment: A quick update: this idea does seem to work well in c++. Everything's coming up Millhouse!

Comment: As a follow up, this does not work in api 2.0 (Maya 2018 sp3). Querying a plug within the compute is a no-go, at least in the python binding.

Comment: @Klaudikus Good to know. I haven't bothered developing much in api 2.0 until it's more matured. I have still been using this with 2018 ext 4, and so far it seems to be working smoothly.